# JavaScript regex to replace repeated characters with one

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace some repeated characters using regex:

```
var string = "80--40";
string = string.replace(/-{2}/g,"-");    // result is "80-40"
```

This replaces two minuses with one, but how could I change the code so that it replaces two or more? I only want one minus symbol to appear between the numbers.

Answer (score 17):

Change it to:

```
string = string.replace(/-{2,}/g,"-");
```

Another way is

```
string = string.replace(/-+/g,"-");
```

as that replaces any one or more instances of `-` with only one `-`.

Answer (score 8):

`{2}` matches exactly two, `+` matches one or more.

```
string = string.replace(/\-+/g, '-');
```

For more on RegEx, [See the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 2):

You can specify `{x, y}` to match any number of repetitions between `x` and `y`. You can also leave off the upper or lower bound, so use `{2,}` instead of `{2}` to replace any matches that occur at least two times.